# In a MFC GUI Application, I want to display the information of on-going process in a console window. Help me out on this

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

The simplified form of the work is given in a button click handler. Sample output not displayed in the window. Help me on this..

```
    void CConsoleWriteExDlg::OnBnClickedButtonConsole()
    {
        if (::AllocConsole())
        {
            HANDLE hOutConsole = ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            DWORD bytes_written;
            ::WriteConsole(hOutConsole, "Sample Output", sizeof(TCHAR) * strlen("Sample Output"), &bytes_written, NULL);
            ::FreeConsole();
        }
    }
```

Comment: does the AllocConsole call succeed? What is the return value of WriteConsole? What is the value of bytes_written?

Comment: Doesn't FreeConsole() close the console, so you can't even see the result?

Comment: FreeConsole(): I can see the output as kept a breakpoint @ FreeConsole.

Comment: well then isn't the problem solved by not using FreeConsole?

Comment: Not Solved stijn. The console window opens, But the write console writes some junk than Sample Output

Comment: Is your application compiled for UNICODE? If so, then it may very well write garbage, or perhaps nothing at all... You are trying to write the ASCII string "Sample Output" and asking to print 13 * sizeof(TCHAR) characters, which may be either 13 or 26.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this project:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15836/Writing-to-and-read-from-the-console-From-a-GUI-ap

Answer (score -1):

Open (evoke) the console using the dot operator and the reference variable. The snippet leaves space for deduction, but it seems that you are calling the functions directly. Try creating an instance and calling the functions for that instance instead.

Create the console instance by defining a reference variable for it (therefore calling the constructor, not sure if the handle was enough for instantiating it). If you want the console to survive, select the function in which you are creating it accordingly.

Hope this helps

Comment: It is a MFC application that uses the win32 api call. The console window opens, but does't print what I want

Comment: I read this answer a dozen times and frankly, I have absolutely no idea what it is trying to say...